# WKWebView Close User Session when App is Terminated

Tags: swift, session, url, wkwebview, applicationwillterminate

Out server has a limit on the number of concurrent sessions.

When user closing and opening the application 2 or more times, our web page is not displayed.
When user killing the application, and then when login again, the server apparently does not have time to track the end of the previous session and initiates a new one. Immediately the restrictions pop up and the application shows a crash screen instead of our web page.

Is there some way to forcefully terminate the user session when exiting the application?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
URLSession.reset()
```

you can try this simply

Comment: And you can explain a little bit more? I didn't find any implementation or sharing of URLSession with WKWebView. Thanks!

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/a-urlsession-crash-and-potential-solutions/4016
I didn't fully understand your code struct but this is very useful article about your question which you can check with your own code.